# How to center an image in ReactJS using css

Tags: css, reactjs, image

I am using ReactJS create-react-app to build a website. I'm trying to center an image on my homepage horizontally across the screen using css, but it is remaining aligned left.

I have the .jpg being imported into a .js file with a class declaration and it appears on the page but it doesn't follow the class modifications I am making in my index.css file.

//in Cur.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import cur from './cur.jpg';

function Cur() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Image
          img src={cur} alt="cur" class="center"
          height={350}
          width={700}
        />
      </div>
    );

}

export default Cur;
```

//in index.css file

```
.center{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<Image
    img src={cur} alt="cur"
    height={350}
    width={700}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
/>
```

You may separate the inline style, or use `styled-components` instead

Comment: when I implement this in the Cur.js file it still remains aligned to the left

Comment: you should add `flex` to the parent element

Answer (score 4):

Set a class name for the div eg. className="container-div"
And style it in your css style sheet.

```
.container-div{ 
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw; 
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

The height and width properties will ensure your container covers the whole screen .

Comment: ...i had to change/correct the spelling on the bottom property. center

Comment: I see, Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

try this.. the property is called className not class

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import from "index.css"
import cur from './cur.jpg';

function Cur() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Image
          img src={cur} alt="cur" class="center"
          height={350}
          width={700}
        />
      </div>
    );

}

export default Cur;
```

Comment: it still is aligned left even with this change, is there something wrong with my .css implementation?

Comment: Also, this is not causing the issue but the prop should be only `src={}` not `img src=""`

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
 <div className="image-container">
    <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
 </div>
```

css file:

```
.image-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: image is from 'react-image-resizer' library

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @Junie.

Answer (score 2):

React uses **className** instead of **class**.
Change

```
img src={cur} alt="cur" class="center"
```

to

```
img src={cur} alt="cur" className="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

my problem was missing `display: flex` in my css styles. adding it to the rest of styles, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In parent div css add:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This will center your image.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import cur from './cur.jpg';

function Cur() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Image src={cur} alt="cur" className="center"/>
      </div>
    );

}

export default Cur;



body,html{
   height:100%,
   min-height:100%
}

.center{
text-align:center;//for texts
height:100%;
display:flex; 
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```